# how to get isHeader/isFooter annotated property via an Apache Camel BindyFixedLengthDataFormat object

Tags: apache-camel, fixed-length-record, bindy

I have some FixedLengthRecord objects that I initialize a BindyFixedLengthDataFormat object via one of those records. First I have to know if that POJO isHeader or isFooter (I have annotated on those pojos), and then other steps:

```
from(myUri)
    .split().tokenize(myToken)
        .process(initializeMyFixedLengthDataFormat)
        .choice()
            .when(/*fixedLengthRecord.IsHeader*/)
                 //do something
            .when(/*fixedLengthRecord.IsFooter*/)
                 //do something
            .otherwishe()
                 //do something
        .end()
    .end()
```

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to fetch if that FixedLengthRecord isHeader/isFooter or not.
Appreciate for any help. (Google could not help.)

Comment: Do you actually want to do anything with the header and footer? Why not just substring out the header and footer and save them as Camel properties?

Comment: I need header and footer. But I have figured out the solution, I think :) I'm going to post  the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bindy object (for my case an object of type **BindyFixedLengthDataFormat**) has a factory property (of type **BindyAbstractFactory**). 
For FixedLengthDataFormat I casted the factory object to **BindyFixedLengthFactory** and reached isHeader/isFooter methods.